# How to build a list nesting if statements

Tags: list-manipulation

Let's say I have a function

```
f[i_,j_]
```

$i$ and $j$ take integer values. $i$ can range from 1 to 20. For any given integer i (between 1 and 20), as you increase $j$ the values $f$ outputs change until we reach some $j$ such that the value we get for $j$ or $j+1$ or $j+10000$ is the same. Let's call this static value the fixed point. I want to make a list such that each element is the static value of a given $i$. How can I build such a list in an economical fashion?

Disclaimer, I haven't specified what $f$ is because this would take way too long and would be more confusing than enlightening

Comment: Can it happen that $j = j+1$ for $j < j_{fixed}$? If so, how can you know that you've actually reached the fixed point?

Comment: Look at the function [`FixedPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPoint.html)

Comment: likely a job for `NestWhile`

Comment: Can you find Limit j-> Infinity of f[i,j]? If so, then you can look for the first j that f[i,j] equals that limit.